# DropDownlist selecteditem can't be retrieved in the redirected page

Tags: c#, asp.net

What i'm trying to fix this morning is a problem with ASP.NET control dropdownlist:

The scenario i'm facing is to retrieve the selecteditem and show in a redirectedpage ( some kind of summary of all user informations ) then give the user the option to submit or edit. but i always get the first item of both dropdownlist.

My code:

```
                mydrop.DataSource = function();
                mydrop.DataTextField = "test";
                mydrop.DataValueField = "type";
                mydrop.DataBind();
                mydrop.SelectedIndex = 0;

                string[] a = new string[] { test.SelectedItem.Text, test2.Text,};
                Session["dataForm"] = a;

                Response.Redirect("~/mypage.aspx");
```

in the page_load of the page i redirect the user to:

```
string[] a = (string[])Session["dataForm"];
        test.Text = a.GetValue(0).ToString();
        test2.Text = a.GetValue(1).ToString();
```

but i always get the first item of the dropdownlist even i change selection.

Thank you for reading and thank you a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Postback issue: do you have if (!IsPostBack) {} on the init of your mydrop?

Comment: test and test are the names i give in the example above to the controls. didnt want to give real names for some reasons. thank you

Comment: Are you binding the dropdownlist in `Page_Load` Method?

Comment: @Pleun I already tried to set property autopostback to true of dropdown but no way! do you suggest to add that condition before getting selected item or populating dropdownlist! thank you

Comment: Solved! thank you a lot @Pleun! I added the famous IsPostBack to my code! Thank you everyone! By the way, any explanations for this issue with ispostback ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you may set the `autoPostback=true` and then put bellow in `Page_Load` for binding:

```
 if(!IsPostback)
 {
            mydrop.DataSource = function();
            mydrop.DataTextField = "test";
            mydrop.DataValueField = "type";
            mydrop.DataBind();
            mydrop.SelectedIndex = 0;

 }
```

Now put the code in `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `mydrop` as follow:

```
protected void mydrop_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string[] a = new string[] { test.SelectedItem.Text, test2.Text,};
   Session["dataForm"] = a;
   Response.Redirect("~/mypage.aspx");
}
```